# Creating a Copy of a Database inside the same machine using Backup/Restore is rasing an errror :- The backup set holds a backup of a database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a copy of my sql server 2008 r2 database (named ERP) inside the same machine. so I did the following steps:-

1. I right click on the original database `ERP` and I select `Tasks>>Backup`.
2. then I create a new empty database named "`ERP_Copy`".
3. I right click on the `ERP_Copy` database, then select restore>>database.
4. inside the restore options I define the To to be `ERP_Copy` and the From to be `ERP`.

then I click to start the process, but I got the following error :-

[image]

so can anyone advice on these 2 questions:-

- what is causing this error ?
- could my original database `ERP` got corrupted or modified due to the error ?? or my ERP should not be modified by my above operation and the error I got ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the error is as stated in the message: you are restoring on a target database that is not the one used as the backup source.

To solve and complete the restore, start the restore, go to the **Options** page and tick the **Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)** checkbox.
**DOUBLE CHECK source and destination database** because the above checkbox would completely smash your production db if you make the wrong choices...

The original database has not been altered by the first (failed) operation.